# Set TravisCI to publish package only when push is on master

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli, travis-ci-api

I'm looking for a way to make an autodeploy of NuGet packages after the compilation. So far I've successfully set the CI/CD on TravisCI but I want to publish the NuGet package only from the `master` branch and not from the `pull request` branch.

This is what the `travis.yml` should look like to make the CI/CD with the deploy.

```
language:
    csharp
sudo: required
mono: none 
dotnet: 3.0

os:
  - linux

global:
- DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true
- DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=true


before_script:
    - dotnet restore solution.csproj 
    - dotnet restore solutionTest.csproj
script:
    - dotnet build solution.csproj --configuration Release
    - dotnet test solutionTest.csproj --configuration Release

after_script:
    - dotnet pack solution.csproj --configuration Release
    - dotnet nuget push bin\Release\*.nupkg -s "some-source"
```

As you can see the process is pretty simple

1. Restore the solution
2. Build the solution
3. Test the solution
4. Generate the NuGet package
5. Push the package to the source

## What do I want

I want this to only happen in the `master` branch after the `pull request` is completed.

## What happens now

When I do a PR to the master branch, in order to be able to be merged it needs to build, so the TravisCI builds everything which builds, test, packs the solution, **and also includes the package publication**, that is what I don't want.

#### Remarks

Can I set the scripts to be run only in a specific branch? Something like the following:

```
[ommited code travis.yml]

branch:
    master:
          after_script:
             - dotnet pack solution.csproj --configuration Release
             - dotnet nuget push bin\Release\*.nupkg -s "some-source"
```

Hopefully this is understandable.